Horror/Thriller, where people see a doll of themselves before being murdered
This color film (American or British) was from the 60's or 70's (saw it on late night TV around 1976).  Before each person is killed they see a doll of themselves that often indicates how they will die (eg: a rope around dolls neck means the person will be killed by hanging).  
In one scene the investigator is going into his car and sees a doll (of himself) but quickly gets away just before the car explodes.
Near the end the murderer ( a young male) winds up (spoiler below)

getting paralyzed by an extremely long heavy chain that falls on him in a massive chain pile.  The scene shows him screaming as the chain accumulates in a pile around him.

The last scene involves the investigator visiting some woman and after the investigator leaves (spoiler below)

you hear the killer who is now in a wheel chair and blind yelling for this woman (sister/wife/mother).

Any ideas as to the name of this film?  thanks

This is the British thriller The Psychopath from 1966.

Inspector Holloway is investigating a series of brutal murders in which a doll of each victim is found at the scene. The dolls, as it turns out,were purchased by the crippled Mrs. Von Sturm, whose home is overcrowded with a doll collection. Her pale, wide-eyed, neurotic son becomes the prime suspect, but are the police mistaken? The daughter of one of the victims discovers the shocking truth.

It ends like you described, with the killer subdued by a huge chain falling on him. Here's the trailer:




Holy smokes - that is awesome - thank you you so, so much!!

Walt doesn't watch movies, movies watch Walt.
